# How to convert Date time from UTC to IST in 12 hours

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

so i have been trying to convert date time which is saved in DB in utc format.
AddedDate: **2022-08-09 12:28:19.717**
Now i want to convert it into ist in a format like this: **Mon, 09 Aug 2022 05:58 PM**

i am using:

**Posted on :** @( TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Model.AddedDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")))

but it was giving me the same format which is saved in database.
(i was rendering the date in view)

Comment: Is your question about _format_ or is it about the time value you get as a result of `ConvertTimeFromUtc`? Because `ConvertTimeFromUtc` returns a `DateTime`, which (by definition) doesn't have a format. I would expect your code to take a UTC DateTime and give you the equivalent time in India.

Comment: You should inspect `Model.AddedDate` in the debugger and check its `Kind` property.  Make sure that it is `Utc` as expected.  If it is not, try using `Model.AddedDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(Model.AddedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);`

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use formatted string. Like this:

```
Model.AddedDate.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You have to convert string to datetime object before you convert it to UTC

```
        string date = "2022-08-09 12:28:19.717"; 
        DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(date); 
        DateTime utcDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        string nzTimeZoneKey = "India Standard Time";
        TimeZoneInfo nzTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(nzTimeZoneKey);
        //Console.WriteLine(nzTimeZone);
        DateTime nzDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(localDateTime, nzTimeZone);
        Console.WriteLine(nzDateTime.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The one liner

```
((DateTime)TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Parse("2022-08-09 12:28:19.717").ToUniversalTime(), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"))).ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The variable named `localDateTime` is a misnomer since it's `Kind` would be `Unspecified` and not `Local`.  You could combine the 2nd and 3rd lines with `DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(date), DateTimeKind.Utc);`  This change also mirrors the intent: that incoming time strings are meant to be UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the code sample below that could help you convert UTC DateTime to IST DateTime and format it.

```
        TimeZoneInfo timzoe = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
        DateTime DT= new DateTime(2022, 08, 09, 12, 28, 19);
        DateTime indiaTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DT, timzoe);  
        string Op= indiaTime.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy hh':'mm tt");
        Console.WriteLine(Op);
```

Output:

```
Tue, 09 Aug 2022 05:58 PM
```

Further, you could modify the code as per your requirements.